# How to avoid " Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort " in MySQL, 21 table JOIN

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.58, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1

I am taking over an old project. I have been asked to speed things up. I have by enabling the slow-query-log. I am examining the queries that appear in the slow-query-log. This query takes 10 seconds to run, and returns 11,000 rows.

```
  select 
    substring_index(ob1.literal,'/',1) AS sku4,
    substring_index(
    substring_index(ob1.literal,'/',2),'/',-(1)) AS sku5,
    substring_index(
    substring_index(ob1.literal,'/',3),'/',-(1)) AS sku6,
    substring_index(ob2.literal,'/',1) AS sku7,
    substring_index(
    substring_index(ob2.literal,'/',2),'/',-(1)) AS sku8,
    substring_index(
    substring_index(ob2.literal,'/',3),'/',-(1)) AS sku9,concat_ws(',',ob.level_one,
    substring_index(ob1.literal,'/',1),
    substring_index(ob2.literal,'/',1)) AS sku1_filter,concat_ws(',',ob.level_two,
    substring_index(
    substring_index(ob1.literal,'/',2),'/',-(1)),
    substring_index(
    substring_index(ob2.literal,'/',2),'/',-(1))) AS sku2_filter,concat_ws(',',ob.level_three,
    substring_index(
    substring_index(ob1.literal,'/',3),'/',-(1)),
    substring_index(
    substring_index(ob2.literal,'/',3),'/',-(1))) AS sku3_filter,
    t.title_id AS title_id,
    t.us_list_price AS us_list_price,
    t.uk_list_price AS uk_list_price,
    t.can_list_price AS can_list_price,
    t.aus_list_price AS aus_list_price,
    t.min_age AS min_age,
    t.max_age AS max_age,
    t.book_club AS book_club,
    t.best_seller AS best_seller,
    t.award_winner AS award_winner,
    t.asin AS asin,
    t.format AS format,
    ob.literal AS literal_1,
    ob1.literal AS literal_2,
    ob2.literal AS literal_3,
    t.series AS series,
    t.volume AS volume,
    group_concat(distinct concat(u.first_name,  ' ',  u.last_name) separator ',   ') AS marketer,
    a.group_letter AS group_letter,
    group_concat(distinct concat(u2.first_name,  ' ',  u2.last_name) separator ',   ') AS editor,
    oi.imprint_name AS imprint_name,
    ob.level_one AS level_one,
    ob.level_two AS level_two,
    ob.level_three AS level_three,
    ot1.territory_name AS rights,  
  (case when (isnull(t.active) or (t.active = '')) 
          then '' when (t.active = 'Y') 
          then 'Active' when (t.active = 'N') 
          then 'In Development' when (t.active = 'X') 
          then 'Terminated' when (t.active = 'T') 
          then 'Transmittal' end) AS status,
  (case when (isnull(t.format) or (t.format = '')) 
          then '' when (t.format = 4) 
          then 'Ebook' when (t.format = 8) 
          then 'Print Book' when (t.format = 9) 
          then 'Audio Book' end) AS format_name,
  t.title AS title,t.primary_isbn13 AS primary_isbn13,
  group_concat(distinct a.display_name order by a.display_name ASC separator ', ') AS contributors,
  group_concat(distinct c1.display_name order by c1.display_name ASC separator ', ') AS publishers,
  t.publish_date AS pub_date,
  group_concat(distinct g.name order by g.name ASC separator ', ') AS category,
  group_concat(distinct g0.id order by g0.id ASC separator ', ') AS secondary_category_ids,
  group_concat(distinct g0.name order by g0.name ASC separator ', ') AS secondary_categories
  from ((((((((((((((((((((wawa_title t 
        left join wawa_title_to_imprint tti on((t.title_id = tti.title_id))) 
        left join wawa_imprint oi on((tti.imprint_id = oi.imprint_id))) 
        left join wawa_title_to_supplier t2a on((t2a.title_id = t.title_id))) 
        left join wawa_territories ot1 on((t.territory_id = ot1.territory_id))) 
        left join wawa_supplier a on((a.supplier_id = t2a.supplier_id))) 
        left join wawa_sku ob on((ob.code = t.sku1))) 
        left join wawa_sku ob1 on((ob1.code = t.sku2))) 
        left join wawa_sku ob2 on((ob2.code = t.sku3))) 
        left join bll_formats tf on((t.format = tf.id))) 
        left join bll_suppliers_to_wawa_editors aoe on((a.supplier_id = aoe.supplier_id))) 
        left join bll_suppliers_to_wawa_marketing_contacts amc on((a.supplier_id = amc.supplier_id))) 
        left join bll_contacts c0 on((c0.id = amc.id))) 
        left join users u on((amc.user_id = u.id))) 
        left join users u2 on((aoe.user_id = u2.id)))
        join wawa_title_to_publisher t2p on((t2p.title_id = t.title_id)))
        join wawa_publisher p on((p.publisher_id = t2p.publisher_id)))
        join bll_contacts c1 on((c1.id = p.org_contact_id))) 
        left join wawa_title_to_genre t2g on((t2g.title_id = t.title_id))) 
        left join wawa_genres g on((g.id = t2g.genre_id_2))) 
        left join wawa_genres g0 on((g0.id = t2g.genre_id_3))) where ((t.title_id = t.title_id) and (t.active <> 'X'))
  group by t.title_id
```

The output of EXPLAIN is:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
  | id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                                                                                 | key                                 | key_len | ref                                      | rows | Extra                                        |
  +----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
  |  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | index  | PRIMARY,org_contact_fk                                                                        | org_contact_fk                      | 5       | NULL                                     |   66 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
  |  1 | SIMPLE      | c1    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                       | PRIMARY                             | 4       | wawa_ripple_development.p.org_contact_id |    1 |                                              |
  |  1 | SIMPLE      | t2p   | ref    | idx_title_id,idx_publisher_id                                                                 | idx_publisher_id                    | 4       | wawa_ripple_development.p.publisher_id   |   66 | Using where                                  |
  |  1 | SIMPLE      | t     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,active_index,idx_title_active_isprimary                                               | PRIMARY                             | 4       | wawa_ripple_development.t2p.title_id     |    1 | Using where                                  |
  |  1 | SIMPLE      | t2g   | ref    | idx_title_id                                                                                  | idx_title_id                        | 4       | wawa_ripple_development.t2p.title_id     |    1 |                                              |
  |  1 | SIMPLE      | g     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                       | PRIMARY                             | 4       | wawa_ripple_development.t2g.genre_id_2   |    1 |                                              |
  |  1 | SIMPLE      | g0    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                       | PRIMARY                             | 4       | wawa_ripple_development.t2g.genre_id_3   |    1 |                                              |
  |  1 | SIMPLE      | tti   | ref    | PRIMARY                                                                                       | PRIMARY                             | 4       | wawa_ripple_development.t.title_id       |    1 | Using index                                  |
  |  1 | SIMPLE      | oi    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                       | PRIMARY                             | 4       | wawa_ripple_development.tti.imprint_id   |    1 |                                              |
  |  1 | SIMPLE      | t2a   | ref    | title_id                                                                                      | title_id                            | 4       | wawa_ripple_development.t.title_id       |    1 | Using index                                  |
  |  1 | SIMPLE      | ot1   | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                       | PRIMARY                             | 4       | wawa_ripple_development.t.territory_id   |    1 |                                              |
  |  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,wawa_supplier_venue_id_supplier_id                                                        | PRIMARY                             | 4       | wawa_ripple_development.t2a.supplier_id    |    1 |                                              |
  |  1 | SIMPLE      | ob    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                       | PRIMARY                             | 29      | wawa_ripple_development.t.sku1         |    1 |                                              |
  |  1 | SIMPLE      | ob1   | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                       | PRIMARY                             | 29      | wawa_ripple_development.t.sku2         |    1 |                                              |
  |  1 | SIMPLE      | ob2   | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                       | PRIMARY                             | 29      | wawa_ripple_development.t.sku3         |    1 |                                              |
  |  1 | SIMPLE      | tf    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                       | PRIMARY                             | 4       | wawa_ripple_development.t.format         |    1 | Using index                                  |
  |  1 | SIMPLE      | aoe   | ref    | idx_by_supplier_and_editor,index_bll_suppliers_to_wawa_editors_on_supplier_id                       | idx_by_supplier_and_editor            | 4       | wawa_ripple_development.a.supplier_id      |    1 | Using index                                  |
  |  1 | SIMPLE      | amc   | ref    | idx_by_supplier_and_marketing_contact,index_bll_suppliers_to_wawa_marketing_contacts_on_supplier_id | idx_by_supplier_and_marketing_contact | 4       | wawa_ripple_development.a.supplier_id      |    1 | Using index                                  |
  |  1 | SIMPLE      | c0    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                       | PRIMARY                             | 4       | wawa_ripple_development.amc.id           |    1 | Using index                                  |
  |  1 | SIMPLE      | u     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                       | PRIMARY                             | 4       | wawa_ripple_development.amc.user_id      |    1 |                                              |
  |  1 | SIMPLE      | u2    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                       | PRIMARY                             | 4       | wawa_ripple_development.aoe.user_id      |    1 |                                              |
  +----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

I am worried about two things:

1.) Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort

2.) Using where

Am I right to be worried about these?

Any suggestions for what I can do to speed things up?

Some variables:

```
  mysql> show variables like '%buffer%';
  +-------------------------+---------+
  | Variable_name           | Value   |
  +-------------------------+---------+
  | bulk_insert_buffer_size | 8388608 |
  | innodb_buffer_pool_size | 8388608 |
  | innodb_log_buffer_size  | 1048576 |
  | join_buffer_size        | 131072  |
  | key_buffer_size         | 8384512 |
  | myisam_sort_buffer_size | 8388608 |
  | net_buffer_length       | 16384   |
  | preload_buffer_size     | 32768   |
  | read_buffer_size        | 131072  |
  | read_rnd_buffer_size    | 262144  |
  | sort_buffer_size        | 2097144 |
  | sql_buffer_result       | OFF     |
  +-------------------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Using index (also type=index) -- This is a 'good' thing.  It says that the work for that table can be done entirely in the BTree of the index, without touching the data.
- Using temporary -- This says that *at least one* temp table is needed for the execution of the query.  There are queries that absolutely must have a tmp table.  So live with it.  Note: the position of this phrase in the `EXPLAIN` does not indicate which table really needs the tmp or filesort.  See `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` for such detail.
- Using filesort -- This says that *at least one* step required sorting.  It does *not* say whether that sort had to hit the disk.  Again, it may be absolutely necessary.
- Using where -- does not mean much of anything
- Using index condition -- This is different than "Using index".  ICP means that a certain efficiency is being used for a complex `WHERE`; this is available only in newer versions.
- eq_ref - One row in the next table is all that is needed.  Good.
- ref - Not 1:1, but 1:many.  From the `EXPLAIN`, it seems to often be closer to 1:1.

As for speeding it up...

- Do you need `LEFT`?  If not get rid of it; the optimizer may prefer some other order of tables.
- The `EXPLAIN` says that not many rows needed to be fetched.  (Caution:  Explain's "Row" numbers are approximates.)  So, I don't see much help here.
- See if you can make "covering indexes" for some of the `JOINs` -- but do this only for the "ref" cases, not the "eq_ref + PRIMARY" cases.  It looks like you have already done a thorough job of this.
- What will you do with 11000 rows?  This seems 'unreasonable' for a UI?  If it is destined for some further processing, how often is it done?  (That is, does 10 seconds really matter?)
- What Engine are you using?  How much RAM do you have?  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%';` -- I am fishing for [memory utilization](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory).
- `JOIN` + `GROUP BY` -- This often means an explosion of rows, followed by an implosion.  Changing *some* of the `JOIN` to subqueries in the `SELECT` *may* improve things: `( SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... LIMIT 1 ) AS whatever`.
- Are any of the fields `TEXT`?  That forces a "filesort" out of memory (hence, slower).  Give me more details and perhaps we can work around it.

In summary, the `EXPLAIN` looks pretty clean.  The huge number of `JOINs` is another matter.

Two *potentially* bad schema designs:

- Arrays across tables (*_price)
- Arrays across columns (level*, sku*, user*, genre*)

**Addenda**

For 16GB of RAM and a mixture of InnoDB and MyISAM, suggest `key_buffer_size = 1500M` and `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 5G`.  Set those in `my.cnf` (or `my.ini`) and restart `mysqld`.

Comment: Thank you. The server has 16 gigs of RAM. The engines are a chaotic mix of InnoDB and MySAMI.

Comment: I added variable data to the main post.

Comment: I added the most important settings -- what you have is extremely low, and is a _part_ of the performance problem.